# Volatile needed here?

Tags: multithreading, gcc, locking, c99, volatile

I have a function where I update a structure, and also disable interrupts.

```
bool readBuffer()
{
    __disable_irq();

    rb->reader += 1; // Just an example

    __enable_irq();

    return true;
}
```

Because interrupts are disabled, its not possible that another interrupt pre-empts while im updating the values in the structure.

But should I also mark the reader variabele as `volatile`? Since in theory the other interrupt could pre-empt while I enter the function, but just before `__disable_irq()` is actually called. And when my function resumes, the cached value of `rb->reader` will be incorrect. Or does the compiler (GCC) generate code that does not cache `rb->reader` untill that line is actually hit?

Comment: Perhaps refer to [volatile considered harmful](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/volatile-considered-harmful.txt) by Linus Torvalds. Does `__disable_irq()` acts as an implicit memory barrier? If yes, then you don't need `volatile` and using it can only hurt.

Answer (score 1):

May be it will be better for you to specify explicit optimization barrier:

```
bool readBuffer()
{
    __disable_irq();
    asm volatile ("" ::: "memory"); // Some unexpected memory modification
    rb->reader += 1; // Just an example
    __enable_irq();
    return true;
}
```

It will be profitable if in some other cases you want compiler to optimize `rb->reader` variable, and marking it volatile will be thus excessive.

Comment: What you have suggested seems to be an optimization barrier right ? Memory barriers are slightly different. Maybe you could prefix a 'lock' instruction in the asm section i.e. 'asm volatile("lock; addl $0, 0(%%esp)":::"memory") . What Joshua needs is a memory barrier but what you have suggested seems more like an optimization barrier which is hinting to the compiler not to rely on values from registers that were populated by code sections before the 'asm'. This does not guarantee that the 'rb->reader += 1' would only be executed after __disable_irq().

Comment: I think, ``volatile`` then is optimization barrier too, not memory one. Thanks for correcting my terminology, edited post. But I suppose, that optimization barrier here is enough, because Joshua worrying more about optimizing out value of rb->reader, that will be impossible in that case.